# Is it possible to create a custom MyAuthorizeAttribute by inheriting (if possible) from the AuthorizeAttribute in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` as follows ?

```cs
[...]
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, ... {
    // Code (overridings e. g.) goes here...
}
```

Thank you for your infos!

Comment: Why? The call is authorized by the authorization middleware, not the attribute. The attribute simply provides some information used by the middleware, eg the role to allow or the complex custom authorization policy to use, which could use [claims added during authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1), database checks etc or [completely custom code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to allow calls only on Tuesdays, noon, when it rains

Comment: Στην περίπτωσή μου πρέπει να το κάνω αυτό. :)

Comment: Why do you want to have to do that? Obviously you can create any attribute you want. If you want it to affect authorization though, you have to modify the middleware, possibly just add a custom policy that uses this attribute

Comment: What if I implement the `IAuthenticationHandler`-Interface? Would it be an easier solution? Τι νομίζετε?

Comment: Authentication means identifying who the user is. Authorization is different, it decides what an already identified user is authorized to do.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what are you trying to achieve we could guide you better. Authorization is easily extansable and you have many ready-made options.

Answer (score 2):

This is [already supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-authorization-attributes). You have to do more than create a custom attribute though. An attribute only stores some information in the generated binary, it doesn't actually affect how an application behaves. It's the application itself that inspects attributes and their values and modifies its behavior.

In this case, the code that authorizes calls is ASP.NET Core Identity. Identity reads the role, claims or policy values stored in `AuthorizationAttribute` and passes them to its default authorization provider. To customize authorization, one has to create a [custom authorization provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-iauthorizationpolicyprovider), not just a custom attribute.

In the documentation's example, the custom attribute modifies the `Policy` value used by ASP.NET Identity based on the `Age` property :

```
internal class MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "MinimumAge";

    public MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute(int age) => Age = age;

    // Get or set the Age property by manipulating the underlying Policy property
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            if (int.TryParse(Policy.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX.Length), out var age))
            {
                return age;
            }
            return default(int);
        }
        set
        {
            Policy = $"{POLICY_PREFIX}{value.ToString()}";
        }
    }
}
```

The custom authorization provider uses that value to authorize a call only if it fulfills its policy:

```
internal class MinimumAgePolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "MinimumAge";

    // Policies are looked up by string name, so expect 'parameters' (like age)
    // to be embedded in the policy names. This is abstracted away from developers
    // by the more strongly-typed attributes derived from AuthorizeAttribute
    // (like [MinimumAgeAuthorize()] in this sample)
    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        if (policyName.StartsWith(POLICY_PREFIX, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            int.TryParse(policyName.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX.Length), out var age))
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            policy.AddRequirements(new MinimumAgeRequirement(age));
            return Task.FromResult(policy.Build());
        }

        return Task.FromResult<AuthorizationPolicy>(null);
    }
}
```